# css pseudo class applied to "a" tag with multiple classes

Tags: css

I have an `<a>` tag, which has several classes applied to it:

```
<a href="WhereInTheWorld" class="class1 class2 class3">
    <span class="c10">
        <span class="fas fa-code"></span>
    </span>
    <p>Textual Healing</p>
</a>
```

I want to apply `a:hover { background-color: black }` to anywhere that has the `a` tag and the `class1` class, but I'm not sure if I'm not doing it right or perhaps the `class2` and `class3` settings are overrding the `:hover` pseudo class

I've tried:

`a.class1:hover`
`a class1:hover`

and

`.class1 a:hover`

which doesn't seem right at all.

It occurs to me I could use an ID for my `a` tag but is it not possible to do it using the existing html setup?

Comment: `a.class1:hover` should work.

Comment: `a.class1.class2:hover` overrides `a.class1:hover`

Comment: I retried `a.class1:hover` and it did work :/ I am now wondering if some cache had been holding on to an older .css file but I'm sure I F5 refresh when trying out the project each time...

Answer (score 2):

`a.class1:hover` seems to be the only correct selector based on the provided HTML. 
`a class1:hover` would select all class1-elements in an a-element and `.class1 a:hover` would select all a-elements within an element with className `class1`.

Take into account the rules of cascading and specificity.

The styling will be overridden

- If there is the same selector somewhere lower in the file
- A selector with a higher specificity is being used (for example a selector with an id)
- Styling is set to child elements specifically

One more thing:

- background-color cannot be set on an `inline` element. You might want to set `display: block` on this element.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQzdEW